# how to make a relation between the user selection from dropdown list and the select query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have PHP script that allow the user to select from 4 dowpdown list  where these dropdown lists includes values retrieved from the MySQL database.

When I tried the SQL query on the phpMyAdmin console it works fine. When I tried in the PHP script it did not work and nothing is retrieved.

@ barmar

first .....

```
<td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

                 <?php
                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
                       $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>
```

second...

```
if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
          }
          else { $site_name=""; }
```

**i am declare the $site_name as global variable**

## SQL query:

```
      $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("select site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
    LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
    on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
    LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
    on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
    LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
    on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
    on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
    ");

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
             echo $site_name;
    echo "<table width='30%' ";
echo     "<tr>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo     "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
    } 


 ?>
```

the new problem is that the when i tried to specify the user selection the query the query stop working.

as wne i add these line :

```
 where 
        site_info.siteNAME = ".$site_name."
```

where $site_name is the variable from the dropdown list

## dropdown list codes:

```
<form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Name</td>
               <td>Owner Name</td>
               <td>Company Name</td>
               <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

                 <?php
                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
                       $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>

                <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
                <?php
                      $query_owner_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT ownerNAME  from owner_info");
                      foreach($query_owner_name as $owner_name)
                      {
                         $owner_name = (array)$owner_name;
                         echo "<option value = '{".$owner_name ['ownerNAME']."}'>".  $owner_name['ownerNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                  ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
                <?php 
                     $query_Company_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT companyNAME  from company_info");
                     foreach($query_Company_name as $Company_name)
                     {
                       $Company_name = (array)$Company_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$Company_name ['companyNAME']."}'>".  $Company_name['companyNAME']."</option>";
                     }  
                 ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Subcontractor names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Subcontractor_name"  name ="Subcontractor_name">
                <?php 
                    $query_Subcontractor_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT subcontractorNAME  from subcontractor_info");
                     foreach($query_Subcontractor_name as $Subcontractor_name)
                     {
                       $Subcontractor_name = (array)$Subcontractor_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$Subcontractor_name ['subcontractorNAME']."}'>".  $Subcontractor_name['subcontractorNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                   ?>
                </select></td>
            <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <input type ="submit" name="query_submit" value ="Search" />

        </td>
       </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: `$query_submit->site_info.siteNAME` is not valid PHP. It should probably be `$query_submit->siteNAME`

Comment: If you turn on error reporting, you should be getting lots of warnings from that code, which would have clued you to the problem.

Comment: @ Barmar the   >site_info.siteNAME  IN ORDER TO  specify the table name because in this query i have to retrieve data from 5 different tables

Comment: `ARRAY_A` means the result is an associative array, why are you accessing it as an object?

Comment: Also, `$query_submit` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows, the second dimension is the columns. You need to loop over all the rows.

Comment: @ barmar i will update my question take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the site name, since it's a string:

```
where 
    site_info.siteNAME = '".$site_name."'
```

But it would be better if you used a prepared statement instead of substituting a variable into the SQL, see [wpdb::prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: still not working i tried to put quotes but nothing is displayed

Comment: Are you sure the query actually finds something? Have you tried running it by hand?

Comment: yes i am sure  that is why i am asking this question... i tried on phpmyadmin console and worked fine  ,,, the $site_name is the variable that handle the user selection from the dropdown list  and based on this selection  the query will display the required values

Comment: the problem is the relation between the variables that handle the user selection from the dropdown list and the sql query

Comment: How are you setting `$site_name`?

Comment: i will add the answer to your question in my question  take a look

Comment: Maybe it's a variable scope problem? Are you doing the query in a different function than the one that sets `$site_name`? Make sure you have error reporting enabled so you see all the warnings.

Comment: its in a different part of the php file  but i declare  it as global

Comment: You have the global declaration inside the function, right? You see the correct value if you echo it right before the query?

Comment: yes after i select from the dropdown list i display the selected values ... i added echo "" before the foreach loop

Comment: Then I'm at a total loss, sorry.

Comment: i know that the problem is in the variable scope .
  `<?php
                 global $site_name;              
                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
                       $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>`

Comment: The `global` declaration has to be in the function that wants to access the global variable, not at top-level.

Comment: Why are you showing the code that sets `$site_name` in a `foreach()` loop. We're only concerned with the code that sets it from `$_POST`.

Comment: i did not understand what you said where is the error in my code ??

Comment: The problem you're having is with the query that contains `WHERE site_info.siteNAME = '$site_name'`. That `$site_name` variable comes from the `$_POST` parameter, right? What does the code you posted in the comment above have to do with it?

Comment: the variable **$site_name** is used to handle the user's selection in the dropdown list so i used in the code of the dropdown.
also 
i check in the if statement  where i assign the **$site_name** to the name of the **dropdownlist**.
then i compared its value inside the **SQL query**

Comment: You're confusing two different invocations of the script. One is used to create the dropdown, that gets sent to the browser, then they submit the form and you need to process the user's selection from the menu. That's in `$_POST['site_name']`

Comment: i know that i must have 2 variables one for the dropdown list  
second to handle the user selection that will be used in the SQL query  so where is my error and how to fix it or re-write the code in proper way

Comment: Put `global $site_name;` in the function that contains `WHERE site_info.siteNAME = '$site_name'`